# React Form UI Not Reflecting State Changes Correctly

Tags: react-hooks, nested, setstate, react-state, react-state-management

I'm working on a nested form in React where a user can have multiple forms, each form can have multiple sections, and each section can have multiple dropdowns. I'm facing an issue where removing a specific dropdown updates the state correctly but does not reflect the correct dropdown being removed in the UI.

I have these States

```
const [addConditions, setAddConditions] = useState([[]]);
const {formIndex} = useContext(FormContext);
const [addConditions, setAddConditions] = useState([[]]);
const { formIndex } = useContext(FormContext);
const [eventValues, setEventValues] = useState([{
    // ...other properties
    conditions: [{ locked: [] }],
    // ...
}]);
```

To add a section

```
const addSection = () => {
    setAddConditions(prev => [...prev, [""]])
}
```

To add a dropdown

```
const addDropdownToSection = (sectionIndex) => {
    setAddConditions(prev => {
        const updated = [...prev];
        updated[sectionIndex].push("");
        return updated;
    });
}
```

I store dropdown values in eventValues

```
const handlePropertyInputChange = (outerIndex, innerIndex, stateType="locked", e) => {
        setEventValues(prevValues => {
            let updatedEvents = [...prevValues];
            let updatedConditions = [...updatedEvents[formIndex].conditions];

            if (!updatedConditions[outerIndex]) {
                updatedConditions[outerIndex] = { locked: [] };
            }
            const { name, value } = extractValue(e);
            updatedConditions[outerIndex][stateType][innerIndex] = {
                ...updatedConditions[outerIndex][stateType][innerIndex],
                [name]: value,
            };
            updatedEvents[formIndex].conditions = updatedConditions;
            return updatedEvents;
        });
    };
```

Problem arises when I have to remove a specific dropdown

```
const removePropertyFromCondition = (sectionIndex, propertyIndex) => {
    setEventValues(prevValues => {
        let updateEvents = makeDeepCopy(prevValues)
        let updatedConditions = [...updateEvents[formIndex].conditions];
        updatedConditions[sectionIndex].locked.splice(propertyIndex, 1);
        updateEvents[formIndex].conditions = updatedConditions;
        console.log({updateEvents})
        return updateEvents
    });
    setAddConditions(prev => {
        const updated = makeDeepCopy(prev)
        updated[sectionIndex].splice(propertyIndex, 1);
        return updated;
    });
};
```

When invoking `removePropertyFromCondition`, the eventValues state is updated correctly (as seen in the console), but in the UI, it's always the last dropdown in the section that gets removed, not the one I intended. After this, any interaction with dropdown values results in the app crashing.

How can I ensure that the correct dropdown is removed in the UI?

I attempted to assign a unique identifier to each section to address the issue, but this approach did not resolve the problem.

Any help is appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue was arising due to unstable keys. I was using array indexes as keys for the mapped `<div/>` but they were changing when elements were being added or removed.
I used UUID's as stable identifiers.

```
{addConditions.map((propertyConditions, outerIndex) => {
    return (
        <div key={propertyConditions.UUID}>
            {propertyConditions.map((propertyCondition, innerIndex) => {
                return (
                    <div key={propertyCondition.UUID}>
                    </div>
                )
            })}
        </div>
    )
})}
```